# Does typeorm block database during migration?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

My application was built by Nestjs, Typeorm and Postgres. Whenever I want to migrate my prod database, I use Github action to run a yarn cmd:
`"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- --dataSource=src/database/data-source.ts migration:run",`

During migration, my database was unaccessible and my service was down.

This is one of my migration on `usage` table that has more than 100000 records

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export class autoGenerate1695182923540 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'autoGenerate1695182923540'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum" RENAME TO "usage_counttype_enum_old"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum" AS ENUM('TICKET', 'REPLY', 'AUTOTAG')`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" DROP DEFAULT`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum" USING "countType"::"text"::"public"."usage_counttype_enum"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" SET DEFAULT 'TICKET'`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum_old"`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum_old" AS ENUM('TICKET', 'REPLY')`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" DROP DEFAULT`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum_old" USING "countType"::"text"::"public"."usage_counttype_enum_old"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "usage" ALTER COLUMN "countType" SET DEFAULT 'TICKET'`);
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum"`);
        await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TYPE "public"."usage_counttype_enum_old" RENAME TO "usage_counttype_enum"`);
    }

}
```

It has run above migration more than 10m but hasn't been completed so I had to stop this job .

Does Typeorm blocks my db ? Is there any alternative to solve this issue ?